# Laravel 4: Basic Auth on RouteGroup without User DB

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-routing, basic-authentication

I want to make a RouteGroup with a Basic Auth Login but without using my User Table for it. Can I set a list of user:pw in a filter or something else so it uses that usernames and pw?

The reason is that I have a dev.domain.tld subdomain (my RouteGroup) and I don't want that other can access that subdomain. Yes i can use the Users Table and check if user == superadmin but at the moment i don't have a Users Table.